# Turning the Stackblitz HelloComponent into a Web Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component, angular-elements

Trying to turn the `HelloComponent` that comes with the Stackblitz Angular default project into a Web Component that runs in the same project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-elements-hello?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Within the `AppModule` I've registered it like this:

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(injector:Injector) {
    const hello = createCustomElement(HelloComponent, { injector }) 
    customElements.define('h-c', hello)
  }

  ngDoBootStrap() {

  }
}
```

And when the app compiles it generates the following error:

> AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: hostEl.createShadowRoot is not a function

Not sure why.  Any ideas?  Also is it possible to run a web component in an Angular Project or does it have to be compiled by itself and then imported?

Comment: That error you getting in stackblitz because you are not running in a native browser. I don't think you will get that error on a local dev environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need a few changed in order to make it work in a Stackblitz environment.

First you need this package :

> @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs

Then you need to add it to polyfills.ts

> import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js'

And also you should remove the

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-elements-hello-x8dpg4)

Comment: Very cool - Thank you!  Is there any particular reason why customElements.define is called in the app.component instead of app.module?  All the tutorial I have seen use ViewEncapsulation.Native?  I noticed you are using either `Emulated` or none.  Could you elaborate on why?

Comment: @Ole probably all the tutorials you seen so far were for local development environment.  And nothing wrong with using `Native`. But in `Stackblitz` environment it wont work. And the `Emulated` value was for testing purposes to see if it is running.